# What is the Lie theoretic interpretation of conjugate of a partition?

Tags: lie-algebras, algebraic-groups, integer-partitions, algebraic-combinatorics

For a partition $\lambda$ it is very well-known operation to take its conjugate partition $\lambda'$ which is obtained by transposing the Young diagram of $\lambda$.

A partition $\lambda$ can be viewed as a dominant weight of $GL_n$ for some $n \geq l(\lambda)$.

Suppose $m \geq l(\lambda),l(\lambda')$. Is there a 'natural' operation on $\mathbb{Z}^m$, the weight lattice of $GL_m$, which takes $\lambda \mapsto \lambda'$ ?

Comment: For one thing, $n\geq l(\lambda)$ does not imply $n\geq l(\lambda^\top)$, so this is unlikely to be something simple.

Answer (score 2):

Computing some simple examples it doesn't appear to be a particularly nice operation. It certainly isn't linear in the weights or anything so simple as that.
Let $\omega_1,\dots,\omega_n$ be the fundamental weights.
Here are some examples of the "transpose the young diagram" operation on weights which I computed using LiE:
$$\begin{array}{|c|c|}
\hline
\omega_1& \omega_1  \\ \hline
 k\omega_1& \omega_k \\ \hline
 \omega_1 + \omega_2 & \omega_1 + \omega_2 \\ \hline
\omega_1 + \cdots + \omega_n & \omega_1 + \cdots + \omega_n \\ \hline
 2\omega_1 + \omega_2&  \omega_1 + \omega_3 \\ \hline
\omega_1 + 2\omega_2 & \omega_2 + \omega_3 \\ \hline
2\omega_1 + 2\omega_2 & \omega_2 + \omega_4 \\ \hline
k\omega_k& k\omega_k\\\hline
(k-i)\omega_k & k\omega_{k-i}\\\hline
k\omega_1 + k\omega_2 & \omega_k + \omega_{2k} \\ \hline
k\omega_1 + k\omega_3 & 2\omega_k + \omega_{2k} \\ \hline
k\omega_2 + k\omega_3 & \omega_k + 2\omega_{2k} \\ \hline
\end{array}$$
Here $i<k\leq n$ (and $2k \leq n$ where it is used).
Caveat: these are patterns I observed and extrapolated so are not proved true for all $k,n,i$.

As you can see there are certainly some patterns but I would be hard-pressed to give a general rule for any weight.

Comment: Interesting... did you put specific values of $k$ and $n$ in LiE and then extrapolate these or can you do all these formally without specifying $k$ and $n$?

Comment: LiE has functions to_part, from_part and trans_part which I joined together (note: you have to append a bunch of $0$'s as trans_part strips them off for some reason which will make from_part give the wrong answer) And then I tried that with various weights. I put in specific values of $k$ and $n$ is the length of the vector you put in (although as long as $n$ is high enough this doesn't change the answers). The patterns are just those I observed so they are not completely guaranteed/may break down for edge cases.

Comment: Another observation I made is that if you decompose $V^{\otimes k}$ into irreducibles the conjugate components seem to have the same multiplicity. Thus you can just compute p_tensor($k,[1,0,\dots,0]$) and pair off things with the same coefficient. I imagine this must be mentioned in some treatments of tensor products of representations but I don't know where off the top of my head.

Comment: Thinking about it a bit harder, my last comment is evident from the [hook length formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hook_length_formula). The multiplicity of each irreducible is given by $f_\lambda = \frac{n!}{\prod h_\lambda(i,j)}$ where $h_\lambda(i,j)$ is the hook length of the cell $(i,j)$ and then $h_\lambda(i,j) = h_{\lambda'}(j,i)$ so $f_{\lambda'} = f_\lambda$ although of course there is no guarantee that there aren't other representations with this multiplicity.